How to evaluate a expression inside a <script> element in JSX using Astro?
I've the following code in an Astro component:
BaseHead.astro
<!-- Schema.org -->
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "LocalBusiness",
    "name": "Sociedad Anonima",
    "description": "Especialistas en gestión logística, almacenamiento y distribución para comercios, industrias y particulares.",
    "image": {`"${url + image}"`},
    "address": {
        "@type": "PostalAddress",
        "streetAddress": "Dirección",
        "addressLocality": "Rafaela",
        "addressRegion": "SF",
        "postalCode": "S2300",
        "addressCountry": "AR"
    },
    "geo": {
        "@type": "GeoCoordinates",
        "latitude": "-31.205",
        "longitude": "-61.415"
    },
    "url": {"${url}"},
    "telephone": "+54-123456789",
    "openingHours": "Mo-Fr 09:00-18:00",
    "sameAs": [
        "https://www.facebook.com/tu-negocio",
        "https://www.twitter.com/tu-negocio",
        "https://www.instagram.com/tu-negocio"
    ]
}
</script>

The problem is that the fields "image" and "url" don't get evaluated by JSX. As a result, nothing change in the values of those fields.
How could I force a JSON field's value to evaluate JSX (inside {})?

From this issue comment:
const schema = {
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "LocalBusiness",
  name: "Sociedad Anonima",
  // ...
}
---
<script type="application/ld+json" set:html={JSON.stringify(schema)}></script>


